# Group Spark Dataset by shorter key without full shuffle

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataset with 4 columns `(c1, c2, c3, c4)`.

I've grouped by `(c1, c2)` and performed some aggregations.

If after that I group by `(c1)` will this grouping operation more effective because of previous grouping?

Comment: I don't know if it will be more effective, but anyway you will have a shuffle, because the same c1 can be in a different parittions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (Spark 2.1) structure like this is not used by the optimizer:

```scala
Seq.empty[(Int, Int, Int)].toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")
  .groupBy($"c1", $"c2")
  .sum("c3")
  .groupBy($"c1")
  .avg($"c3")
  .explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[c1#130], functions=[avg(c3#142L)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(c1#130, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[c1#130], functions=[partial_avg(c3#142L)])
      +- *HashAggregate(keys=[c1#130, c2#131], functions=[sum(cast(c3#132 as bigint))])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(c1#130, c2#131, 200)
            +- *HashAggregate(keys=[c1#130, c2#131], functions=[partial_sum(cast(c3#132 as bigint))])
               +- LocalTableScan <empty>, [c1#130, c2#131, c3#132]
```

As you can see Spark schedules two independent `Exchanges` instead of using more general grouping for both aggregation. So in practice the answer depends on two factors:

- Aggregation function. If function operates with a constant memory footprint and applies "map-side" reduction (like `sum`) then the lower entropy can increase amount of data that can be reduced locally and decrease shuffle size.
- Values distribution. `c1` cardinality has to be high enough for multiple `(c1, c2)` levels being assigned to a single partition in the first aggregation. If there is only reduced row per `c1` value per partition there is nothing to gain.

If both conditions are satisfied you should see some performance gains.